# Bluetooth client/server communication between computer and mobile phone

Tags: java-me, bluetooth, midp, bluecove, jsr82

I need just a basic example or tutorial of making a mobile phone and a computer communicate via *Bluetooth*.

A good link/website to start from is also appreciated.

Server part (computer part) can be made on many programming languages (*Java*, *C++*, *Python* or even something else).

Client part (mobile phone) must be a *Java Micro Edition* MIDlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many days of research, I managed to make an application that sends (in real time) screenshots of area around the mouse cursor on a computer to a mobile phone client.

Both client and server are written in Java.
I used [**BlueCove**](http://bluecove.org/) to make the desktop part. It is a JSR-82 implementation (the same protocol as in MIDP), so desktop and mobile parts share a lot of code.

---

In case someone needs it, I release the application as public domain, without any responsibilities.

[**Download the code**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8vd1x4cmde8s9gg/BluetoothClientServer.zip?dl=0)

I'm not really proud of it. After all, I was 15 when I wrote it. The code is horrible in some places, but I enjoyed making the abstraction for code reuse.

Comment: Can you help me solve my problem.. please post in details how you created the server j2se and the client j2me ... just by a simple function or 2 for each of them.. I need it badly.. and i am not getting my answer here.