# Bluetooth j2se and j2me

Tags: java, api, bluetooth

I i developing a software where users send message through bluetooth from their j2me enable phone. The server (bluetooth enabled laptop) recieves it and send some acknowledge message.

basically 2 software  j2se server and j2me client

How do I do it? I need to do this under netbeans. Where do i start? any API that works in both j2me and j2se? .. Dont have much time so need a simple one. Security is not a issue,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of [**Bluetooth client/server communication between computer and mobile phone**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198306/bluetooth-client-server-communication-between-computer-and-mobile-phone)

Please look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198306/bluetooth-client-server-communication-between-computer-and-mobile-phone/3231927#3231927) there.