# getting started with computer (linux) based bluetooth device making it discoverable for surrounding phones

Tags: java, linux, bluetooth, bluecove

I am looking for a basic code example, or even better a corresponding tutorial, for a program taking advantage of the local bluetooth hardware to act as one (or more) bluetooth device which can then be discovered/seen/talked to by a nearby phone/device which has bluetooth capability without the need to install a corresponding app, as phones normally already have a bluetooth manager listing nearby devices which I want to use.

I already dug into [Bluecove](http://bluecove.org/) and some other semingly corresponding [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867334/bluetooth-j2se-and-j2me). But either there is no entry level documentation or only code is provided.

Any entry level code base, tutorial or helpful pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd greatly appreciate a reason why I got a downvote/close-vote (off-topic). I am new to this area of programming (java + bluetooth) and am looking for pointers to get started as reading the bluecove API did not get me anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

googling for it I found https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/07/27/bluetooth.html which seems to answer your question perfectly.

Comment: must have slipped me, but explains the downvote. Thx